# Downgrade SDK Dart to build App on MacBook

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I have an old MacBook here, and I need to build an app on it to test on an iPhone, the problem is that the app was created using the newest version of flutter. And as you may know, MacBook does not allow to install Flutter in XCode older than Flutter version 13,
and I was wondering if I would downgrade the Dart/Flutter SDK I will have problems and how to solve them?

the message displayed on console is:

```
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
! Flutter recommends a minimum Xcode version of 13.
Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
• CocoaPods version 1.10.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install other versions of flutter to build your application with it. You can either do so manually or use the [flutter version manager](https://fvm.app/) (fvm) for that.

Download links for all flutter releases can be found in the [flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases).

These older releases of flutter then have different requirements for the Xcode versions.